# Why Horizontal Slider isn't work in View?

Tags: uikit, swift4

I have some trouble with my slider, when I put it on View, it isn't work.

I create simple interface:
[image: Interface]

[image: Interface tree]

First slider in my interface isn't work, but second is work perfectly.
I found that in my Xcode nothing work in View, buttons, slider and etc.

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
}
```

XCode Version - 11.3.1
MacOS Version - 10.15.1

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that it is incredibly difficult to help with coding problems if we can't see the code. Please consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Hm, what code do you need if i didn't change anything?

Comment: Where came this simple interface "Test" come from?

Comment: I created it in Main.storyboard without coding

Comment: Make sure constraints are proper for UIView and UISlider, and userInteractionEnabled is set to true.

Comment: Already setted https://imgur.com/a/ifLVRib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it, you only need to set height for your View.